# How to get all JTable rows into a String Array?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I've got a JTable in my program that has 4 columns

ID(int) -- Name(string) -- Qty(int) -- Usage(int)

Each time the JTable is populated it has a different amount of data. What I would like to do is to grab all of the data from the table (IE X amount of rows lets say 5) and save all of them to a String Array; Or if you have a better method.

Ultimately I want to take the table data and save it to a text file. I've looked at other SOF questions and saw an object method but I'm not sure that does what I'm looking for.

Thoughts ?

EDIT: Current Code (Working but seems dirty; is it correct?)

```
String[][] tableString = new String[table_Drops.getRowCount()][table_Drops.getColumnCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < table_Drops.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tableString[i][0] = String.valueOf(table_Drops.getValueAt(i, 0));
        tableString[i][1] = String.valueOf(table_Drops.getValueAt(i, 2));
        tableString[i][2] = String.valueOf(table_Drops.getValueAt(i, 3));
        tableString[i][3] = String.valueOf(table_Drops.getValueAt(i, 4));
    }
```

Comment: You could shorten that with a nested loop, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765540/7644018). Seems to be generally similar to what you've done.

Comment: `Ultimately I want to take the table data and save it to a text file` - so why do you want to save it to a String array first. That is extra processing. Just get the data from the table and write it to the file in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, the only unclean part are the magic numbers you have while accessing your `JTable`. You could use a nested loop for this.

Writing the data to a `File` is straight forward with a `FileWriter`:

```
private static void writeTableDataByRowAmount(JTable table, int rows) throws IOException
{

    String pathToFile = "C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\file.txt";
    String text = "";

    for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<table.getColumnCount() ; j++)
        {
            text += table.getValueAt(i, j);
            text += " ";
        }
    }

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToFile));
    writer.write(text);
    writer.close();
}
```